# How can I quickly start typing SQL in Microsoft Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ide

In Microsoft Access 2016, I would like to click somewhere and start typing SQL of new query right away. But the shortest way to start typing SQL (which I found so far) is:

1. Select menu **Create** > **Query Design**.
2. In **Show Table** window, press **Close** button.
3. Switch to SQL view.
4. Start typing SQL.

Too cumbersome. Can be the above steps 1–3 reduced to a shorter procedure? Did I overlook some command?

The fastest I can do is to put commands for steps 1 and 3 to Quick Access Toolbar and then I can for example do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>. But this still only executes steps 1–3.

Comment: Step 1: Try ALT + C then ALT + CD
The only way that I know to skip step 2, is to press the ESC key.

Comment: @JonTout – I am doing this, question updated. But this still goes through the same 3 actions.

Comment: That's it. Adopt. It will not be changed/improved.

Comment: @Gustav - no. AHK is still a solution. :)  But maybe someone found some shorter way without it. You know, VBA is not dead. Btw are you from the Microsoft that you know the above is the shortest way and that "It will not be changed/improved."? Thanks.

Comment: There has been suggestions to improve the SQL query editor made in the euphemistically named "User Voice"  here https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop for years. They have to date fallen on deaf ears, even though supported by a large number of MVP's and other Access illuminati - Good luck.

Comment: @Minty – [I see](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/10191753-open-query-in-sql-view), thanks. So hopefully that after this Q/A they can serve themselves at least by faster opening that editor :)

Comment: No, I'm an MVP in Office/Access, that's all, but as @Minty mentions, the subjects (improving/modernising the SQL editor and the VB editor) have been brought up many times and, sadly, there is not a single sign for this to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function below creates or alters a simple placeholder query, opens it in Design View, switches to SQL View with its text highlighted, and then deletes the text.

Use the function as the `RunCode` action of a macro and add the macro to the Quick Access Toolbar.  Then you can click that icon and start typing your SQL.

```vba
Public Function NewQuery()
    Const cstrQueryName As String = "USysQuery0"
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strSql As String

    strSql = "SELECT Date() AS Today;"

    Set db = CurrentDb
    For Each qdf In db.QueryDefs
        If qdf.Name = cstrQueryName Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If qdf Is Nothing Then
        Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(cstrQueryName)
    End If
    qdf.SQL = strSql
    qdf.Close
    DoCmd.OpenQuery cstrQueryName, acViewDesign
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSQLView
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDelete
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer, I like it. I will consider this one for databases which already have some codebase so this can be added there. (Unlike in MS Outlook, in Access it is not possible to have some VBA code outside the databases, right? If we do not count plugins.) In the meantime I found my previously created AHK code to be suitable for new databases without code base. Future will show with which one I will stick. :)

Comment: Seems to me if your database doesn't have VBA code modules, you wouldn't want a macro either.  So while not suitable for you, this is convenient for me with my databases, and I'm glad you asked the question. :-)

Comment: I realized that the solutions complement themselves. Per single deployment, yours is database-dependent: single database, but multiple computers and multiple users. Mine is computer-dependent: single computer, typically single Windows user, but multiple databases. So they give readers alternatives to fit their scenario.

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for better answer, I created an [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) solution – a keyboard shortcut (restricted only to Access) to perform the above steps in English language version of Microsoft Access 2016:

```c
SendMode Input                                      ; // Choose mode of sending keystrokes

#IfWinActive, ahk_class OMain ahk_exe MSACCESS.EXE  ; // Only in scope of MS Access app

+^n::                                               ; // Routine for Ctrl+Shift+N starts
    Send !cqd                                       ; // Run "Query Design" menu command
    WinWaitActive,Show Table ahk_class #32770       ; // Wait for "Show Table" window
    Send {Esc}!jqwq{End}{Left}{Space}               ; // Send the rest of the keys
    Return

#IfWinActive                                        ; // end of #IfWinActive section
```

After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and waiting a bit*, a new query window is open in SQL view and I can start typing SQL.

*) Sometimes, MS Access can be really slow on keyboard shortcuts accessing the ribbon and on switching from query Design View to SQL View.

Comment: I like that approach!

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: deal with it.

By default, Access doesn't support anything faster than this.

Option 2: create a macro in your Access database to automate the task, and bind this to a key combination

You could write a macro to automate command bar actions, and [bind that macro to a shortcut](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/run-an-access-macro-by-using-a-keyboard-shortcut-0d267570-d3da-46eb-9bfb-a3c81af676be). I currently don't have time to look up the required commands but am certain it's possible.

Option 3: buy a plugin

There are plugins out there that immediately go to SQL view, support having the SQL and results on the same pane, have syntax highlighting, etc.

An example of such a plugin is [Access SQL editor](https://fieldeffect.info/wp/access-sql-editor-documentation/) (I'm not affiliated in any way)

Option 4: Create your own.

Writing your own SQL editor that's better than what Access offers by default is very simple, because Access offers very little by default.

You can start off with a form with a textbox that takes the SQL, a save button, an execute button (requires a little VBA), and a subform that displays the query results. Then you already have something that allows you to open it and start typing right away.